# How to scroll contents WHILE scrolling

Tags: winforms, user-controls, scroll

I have created a usercontrol that is essentially a text editor (using Graphics.Drawstring in OnPaint).

I have set AutoScroll = true, and AutoScrollMinSize values appropriately. Everything is working how it should...

EXCEPT, i would like the control to scroll itself WHILST I am currently scrolling (i.e. click and drag the scroll bar... and whilst it is being dragged the control should be scrolling the entire time). At the moment it only scrolls when the scroll bar is released (mouse up).

I have tried implementing _Scroll and invalidating the control, but that just makes it flicker uncontrollably.

I cannot find any examples online for this, due to it being difficult to describe!

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Post code that duplicates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Control.Invalidate()` will make something flicker badly. I faced this problem drawing cross-hairs over a mouse position on a `PictureBox` drawing a line chart before. The trick is to use (and I cant remember which one is best to come first)

```
Control.Update();
Control.Refresh();
```

in the `Scroll` event. Depending on what else you are drawing in the `Control` and how you are drawing it this may be better for you. Also this is tested on `PictureBox`, `Control` may be another matter.

Comment: No for some reason thats not working, no matter which way round i have them.

Comment: Actually, it worked. Not sure what i was doing wrong, but Refreshing before updating has done the trick. Thanks!